# How can I find all values between strong brackets from a javascript website using Selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, python, javascript

I'm trying to scrape a javascript website. The website contains a list of products and I need to find out a specific product through this list. All product names are between strong brackets from an HTML perspective.

example: `<strong>product name</strong>`

I'm able to find only the first product in the list using this code below, how can I find other products ?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


my_url = 'https://order.koomi.com/comptoir-sainte-cecile-VwRWLYwwkd/fr/2018030601/takeout/menu/vins-rouges-36?fbclid=IwAR0jMjQtHoZyNLSlafvvPKHn9OkNMsCN4BdAjgfaigdVvyed3aZRS0Ij4tw'
    
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("/home/pi/chromedriver")
    driver.get(my_url)
    time.sleep(5)
    #htmlSource = driver.page_source
    
    entries = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//strong')
    print(entries.text)
```

Comment: Welcome to the community. find_element_by_xpath() only finds 1 instance. Have you tried find_elements_by_xpath()? This will put all found entries into an array.

Comment: it does but instead of having product name it returns the code below for each product.<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="64c8ef24cac37169cfd92572fc1937c4", element="83a11039-9c74-4e89-905b-d254b9796456")>

Answer (score 1):

To get all the content within every `<strong></strong>` tag in a web page, here is a sample code in **Java**:

```
//Get list of web-elements with tagName  - strong
 List<WebElement> allProducts = driver.findElements(By.tagName("strong"));
 
 //Traversing through the list and printing its text
 for(WebElement product:allProducts){
    System.out.println(product.getText());
 }
```

You can use something on the similar lines in Python.

**Edit:**

I haven't tried this personally, but based on online search I've got this for **Python**,

```
list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('strong')

for li in list:
    print(li.text)
```

You can try and let me know if that works.